# How to integrate Request Tracker 4.0 with Open LDAP in Debian?

Tags: apache-httpd, openldap

I want my `ldap` users to log in to `RT`and see the tickets. I have gone through `RT` [documentation](https://www.bestpractical.com/docs/rt/4.2.0/authentication.html) but it's a bit complicated for me as I'm just a starter. 
I do understand that I have to edit `/etc/request-tracker4/RT_SiteModules.pm` and  `/etc/request-tracker4/apache2-modperl2.conf` but some examples for a simple configuration will be really helpful.

I got an existing mail server and I have installed RT on top of it. All the mails to helpdesk@domain.lcl are coming into `Request Tracker` but I have to login as `root` to see them. I want all the ldap users (such as `harry@domain.lcl`) to see them. When I am trying to login as `ldapuser`, not being able to login